# Removing Kivy's Window border

Tags: python, kivy

According to the kivy document, I can remove Window's border by `Window.borderless = True`
(https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html)

However, The problem is, it still shows the border when it starts up, then it gets removed in like 0.5 second. And it seems a bit weird to me

Is it possible to remove the border at the very beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by first reading the Config and probably configured to be border and then read your configuration, so the solution in that case is to save it in the config, so a second load of the application will no longer watch that transition.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config

Config.read("myapp.ini")
if Config.getint('graphics', 'borderless') == 0:
    Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
    Config.write()
    Window.borderless = True


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: It still shows the border for the first time this way, but I get the idea.

Comment: Oh, but this changes all other kivy apps also. It is possible to modify only this app's setting?

Comment: @BerryMan I have updated my answer so that it only affects the application.for more information read https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html#local-configuration